# How to remove the space from the top in xamarin form?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="WindyBox1.InputPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#2051fb">
            <Label Text="WindyBox"
                   FontSize="15"/>
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Coolers}"
                            SelectionMode="Single"
                            BackgroundColor="#4fa1fb"
                            SelectionChanged="SelectChanged">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="10"
                              RowDefinitions="Auto, *"
                              ColumnDefinitions="Auto, *">
                            <Image Source="Cooler.png"
                                   WidthRequest="80"
                                   HeightRequest="80"
                                   Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                   Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                   Grid.Column="1"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Condition}"
                                   TextColor="LightGreen"
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                   Grid.Column="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
            <Button Text="Подключиться к устройству"
                    x:Name="ConnectDeviceButton"
                    IsEnabled="False"
                    Clicked="ConnectDeviceButton_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I got a space at the top.
If you prescribe something, [it still remains](https://gifyu.com/image/SLH4v). Can you tell me how to remove this unoccupied space from above?
I would like to put a button or something else there.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c3NZ.png)

Comment: I used your code but i don't see the space above , can you show you WindyBox1.InputPage.xaml.cs .     https://i.ibb.co/TqDgXW4/screen.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the Navigation Bar. Disable it using  `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"`

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="WindyBox1.InputPage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false">
```